# Is it Possible to extract object properties as a sequence in F#

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# - In nodejs - it's possible to extract & enumerate an objects properties.  Is it possible to get this data in F#?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: It's not possible using F# proper, but you can use backdoors (reflection). You should get answers telling you how to do this. But please don't do it! You will lose all the statically typed benefits of F# and .Net.

Comment: If it's just for debugging, try `printfn "It is %A" something`

Comment: @CharlesRoddie  thanks - I have mapped SQL entities to objects using https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider//core/mappers.html    - but I can't figure out how to map them back so I can update them

Comment: If you declare your types as [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records) or [DU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions) than you get pretty-print out of box

Comment: @JL0PD - thanks , does that mean you can map back from records to database form and update using an object?